# Does Sanskrit निस् • (nis) "out, forth, away" come from PIE *ni- "in; down?" with meaning shift from "in" to "out"?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, semantics, proto-indo-european, sanskrit

[निस्·nis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D#Sanskrit) "out, forth, away" > [nirvana](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3#Etymology_2) "to blow out, extinguish; out of breath?"

[नि·ni](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF#Sanskrit) "down, back, in, into" < [PIE *h₁én](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%81%C3%A9n) "in; down?"

My question is whether these words are from the same PIE root? And If they are cognates, how does the meaning shift from "in" to "out"?

PS: this is a post involving diachronic semantics, which I assume to be a subbranch of linguistics, so why did the close-voters vote "off-topic" option?

Comment: Canada (or Greek is it now? I still prefer LePressentiment), did you create a new account? Why?

Comment: @DanBron, Hi, my account is not a new one, please check my question list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanskrit ni “down” and niṣ “out” are two different words. The former is cognate with the first part of German “nieder”. The latter does not have any assured cognates outside of Indo-Iranian.

Comment: Thanks for your cognancy infomation, if there is no cognate candidates, maybe semantic connection is unnecessary .